# how do you write integers to an external file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**i am trying to create a leaderboard for a game and need to decide if a players score is there high score or not but every time i try to run the program it says " '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" what do i do**

heres my code:

```
score = 0

s = open("highscore.txt", 'r') 
scores = s.read() 
s.close()

if score > (scores):
    highscore = score

s = open("highscore.txt", 'w') 
s.write(highscore)
s = open("highscore.txt", 'r') 
scores = s.read() 
s.close()

print(f"your score was {score}")
```

Comment: `score` is an integer and `scores` which you read from the file is a string so you can't compare them both, since the error. If the file only contains one number you can do something like `int(s.read())` to use it as `int.`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert to a string and back again.

For example, here is how you could write the number to a file.  By calling `str(highscore)` it converts it to the equivalent string (e.g. `'0'`). This can then be written to the file.

```
with open("highscore.txt", 'w') as s:
   s.write(str(highscore))
```

You can optionally also add a newline if you use `s.write(str(highscore) + '\n')`, but it will work without it.

Here is how you would read the whole contents of the file - i.e. the string that you wrote - and convert it to an integer using `int()`. This relies on the fact that the file only contains the number and nothing else.

```
with open("highscore.txt") as s:
   highscore = int(s.read())
```

Note also the pattern for reading and writing files using `with`.  It is probably best to learn this as-is for now, but note that you do not need a `close` statement when doing it this way.

Comment: The error didn't occur when he was writing or reading the file, it happened when he was comparing them.

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan But the underlying problem was that he didn't convert it to int as part of reading it in.

Comment: Reverse the code blocks and it would be better, this is a little confusing since he is a beginner and probably won't be able to understand it.

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan Okay, I'll add some additional explanation if that would help.

Comment: Sure that would be better

Answer (score 0):

When you use a read() method it returns a string. That means value in "scores" is a string and you cannot compare a String with an integer. Hence you need to typecast it.

```
if score > int(scores):
    highscore = score
```